# How to do 24.89 / 26.15 with long division?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

How to do 24.89 / 26.15 with long division? Question is to find applied tax if 24.89 is pre-tax and 26.15 is post-tax. I'm aware of how to solve this with a calculator (1-(24.89/26.15))= ~.0482 = ~ 4-5 cents

Comment: Do you know how to do $2489 / 2615$ with long division?  Notice that for $b\neq 0$ and $c\neq 0$ you have $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{ac}{bc}$.  So, $\frac{24.89}{26.15} = \frac{2489}{2615}$.  Also, be careful about what tags you use.  This has absolutely nothing to do with division algebras.

Comment: $\frac {2489}{2615} $

Comment: What's after the first step? I know 2489 goes into 2615 once ... then apply the decimal ... then 2489 goes into (2615-2489) 0 times which begins a fraction ... how do you show the rest with long division?

Comment: Don't let decimal points throw you off. $24.89=2489/100$.

Comment: Except that the applied tax (as a proportion of the pre-tax price) is $\frac{26.15}{24.89}-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply top and bottom by $100$, getting $\frac {2489}{2615}$.  Then divide the way you were taught.  As you say, if you want the difference from $1$, it is $1-\frac {2489}{2615}=\frac {126}{2615}\approx 0.0482$$

Comment: yes, but how do you show 126 / 2615 with long division?

Comment: You just divide $2615$ into $126.000000000$.  I was taught that if you want the decimal, you do this multiplication to clear the decimals in the denominator, then add zeros after the decimal point and align the decimal point in the quotient with the decimal point.  So $2615$ doesn't go into $1260$, which gets the $0$ after the decimal.  Then $2615$ goes $4$ times into $12600$ leaving $2140$. Bring down the next zero, and $2615$ goes into $21400$ eight times and so on.